# Elixir Processes Monitoring: :EXIT vs :DOWN

Tags: elixir

I usually see examples of process monitoring where the code for handling a monitored process exit is the following:

```
handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, pid}, state)
```

But I have also seen examples where they are matching an `:EXIT` instead of a `:DOWN` message.

So far, I have only been able to trigger `:DOWN` messages in my own examples, which includes standard `Process.exit` and `GenServer.stop` messages, as well as raising an exception in the monitored process.

When will I receive an `:EXIT` message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:EXIT` is sent to the process that another process tried to exit using `Process.exit` (with a reason other than `:kill`) but the process was trapping exits. `:DOWN` is sent to a process that is monitoring another process and the monitored process exits for any reason.

Here's an example of both:

```
pid = spawn(fn ->
  Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
  receive do
    x -> IO.inspect {:child, x}
  end
end)
Process.monitor(pid)
Process.sleep(500)
Process.exit(pid, :normal)
Process.sleep(500)
# A process cannot trap `:kill`; it _has_ to exit.
Process.exit(pid, :kill)
receive do
  x -> IO.inspect {:parent, x}
end
```

Output:

```
{:child, {:EXIT, #PID<0.70.0>, :normal}}
{:parent, {:DOWN, #Reference<0.0.8.223>, :process, #PID<0.73.0>, :normal}}
```